# How to merge multiple kafka streams in order to do a session windowing over all events of the resulting stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

We have multiple input topics with different business events (page views, clicks, scroll events etc). As far as I understood Kafka streams they all get an event timestamp, which can be used for KStream joins with other streams or tables to align the times.

What we want to do is: Merge all different events (originating from the above mentioned different topics) for a user id (i.e. group by user id) and apply a session window to them.

This should by possible by using `groupByKey` and then `aggregate/reduce` (specifying the Inactivity time here) on a stream containing all events. This combined stream must have all events from the different input topics in an order of the event time (or in a way that the above kafka streams methods honor this event times).

The only challenge that is left, is to create this combined / merged stream.

When I look at the Kafka Streams API, there is the `KStreamBuilder#merge` operation for which the javadoc says: `There is no ordering guarantee for records from different {@link KStream}s.`. Does this mean the Session Windowing will produce incorrect results?

If yes, what is the alternative to #merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also thinking about joining, but in fact it seems to depend if you have one event per topic per ID, or potentially multiple events with the same ID within one input topic. For the first case, joining is a good strategy but not for the later, as you would get some unnecessary duplication.

```
stream A: <a,1> <a,2>
stream B: <a,3>
join-output plus session: <a,1-3 + 2-3>
```

Number `3` would be a duplicate.

Also keep in mind, that joining slightly modifies the time stamps and thus your session windows might be different if you apply them on the join result or on the raw data.

About `merge()` and ordering. You can use `merge()` safely as the session windows will be build based on record timestamp and not offset-order. And all window operations in Kafka Streams can handle out-of-order data gracefully.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. As we have multiple events in a topic for the same user id ( e.g. "clicks") we would have duplicates.

The comment about ```merge()``` using record timestamps and not offset ordering (so merge may change offset order) but you can safely use merged streams for identifying sessions on the merged messages would be a very good addition to the scala/java doc for it.

Comment: @longliveenduro Agree that the JavaDocs could cover that. We do accept PRs :)

Comment: Agree with Matthias that first using builder.merge() to generate a single stream and then do a session windowed aggregate would be a good approach. Plus, if these source topics have the same data types, you can even directly generate a single stream at the beginning with multiple topics (i.e. you do not have to create one stream per topic and then merge them).

Note that for any windowed aggregations Kafka Streams does handle late arrived data so that even the record in the streams may not come in order, they can still be sessionized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> What we want to do is: Merge all different events (originating from the above mentioned different topics) for a user id (i.e. group by user id) and apply a session window to them.

From what I understand, you'd need to [join the streams](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#joining) (and use `groupBy` to ensure that they can be properly joined by user id), not merge them.  You can then follow-up with an session-windowed aggregation.

Comment: Yes, joining two sources would be easy to do. We could easily define a Join Window which resembles somehow our session window. But what about 3 and more source streams? When you've joined the first two, what Join Window do you specify for joining that with the third source to get the desired "over all " Session Window and so on?

Comment: So what you point out is probably this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/StreamToStreamJoinIntegrationTest.java 
But what if you have 3 or more topics? What JoinWindow would be correct than?